# How to get the Selected Row Number in QTableView?

Tags: qt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the Selected Row Number from QTableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878643/how-to-get-the-selected-row-number-from-qtableview)

i am new QT. i am using QTableView to display the Data.

if any cell clicked, then i need to call the event to display the row number in QMessageBox.

which event i need to use, and how to call the event?

please help me to fix the problem.